# How to handle multiple files and messages for internationalization in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

Some articles about Spring internationalization tell how to swap messages passing the locale and etc, **but I only found use cases that contains a few messages**..

- How can I organize and use internationalization files per context? (validation, view messages, default messages, business messages)
- I know that Spring uses the pattern (name of message file defined) +
  locale. **e.g: message_zh_CN**. How can I have files per context knowing
  about this behavior?

What I think it should be:

```
resources
`-- messages
    |-- validation
    |   |-- message_locale.properties
    |   `-- message_locale2.properties
    |-- business
    |   |-- message_locale.properties
    |   `-- message_locale2.properties
    `-- view
        |-- message_locale.properties
        `-- message_locale2.properties
```

OR:

```
resources
`-- messages
    |-- validation
    |   |-- validation_locale.properties
    |   `-- validation_locale2.properties
    |-- business
    |   |-- business_locale.properties
    |   `-- business_locale2.properties
    `-- view
        |-- view_locale.properties
        `-- view_locale2.properties
```

Comment: What stops you from using your preferred structure. I don't see the question here to be honest.

Comment: In the samples I saw only one file and I'm a little bit confuse about how use more files

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can either define a global `MessageSource` for all those different message files. This approach is practical using the `setBasenames` method:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = 
                                               new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/messages/business/message", 
                               "classpath:/messages/validation/message",
                               "classpath:/messages/view/message");

    return messageSource;
}
```

This approach makes sense if your message keys are unique across all files, e.g. `business-12` key only exits in business related message sources. Otherwise, it's better to define one `MessageSource` per context and inject them according to your context:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource businessMessageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = 
                                               new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages/business/message");

    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource validationMessageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = 
                                               new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages/validation/message");

    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource viewMessageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = 
                                               new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages/view/message");

    return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: Nice.. it's simple but I was not getting how to do!! Thanks!

Comment: if anyone is stuck doing this, please note that the file extension .properties MUST NOT be added, else Spring will not use that file. So, no `messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages/validation/message.properties");`   :(

Comment: @Ali Dehghani: If I follow your second approach and have different MessageSources with different "names". I want to use the <spring:message> tag in a jsp. How is dermined from which MessageSource the property is loaded?

Comment: Using the second approach, how would you access those different messageSources using the JSTL spring message tag? I don't see any way to specify the beanName.