# Internationalization in the Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I create internationalization for my application and am wondering if I can create several files to create translated messages. I do not think it's advisable, but I prefer to ask.

The thing is that I have a 'messages.properties' file where I have some text already

```
http s://pastebin.com/WdyE0Aaj
```

And this is just the beginning. What if I will have dozens of pages and for each page I will have to declare here translation. After all, this file will go on in the hundreds and then thousands. Can it be somehow divided into more files?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/40165151/8198056

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can (and probably should, to keep things maintainable).

The [Spring-boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) says:

> ```
> spring.messages.basename=messages # Comma-separated list of basenames, each following the ResourceBundle convention.
> ```

So, just add as many basenames as you want to your spring boot properties/yaml file, and they will all be agregated in a single MessageSource. Just make sure to avoid conflicts in the i18n property names.